# Reading huge binary file (~1.5 GB) and writing the results to a text file C++

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream

I am trying to read a huge binary file, chunk by chunk, decode each chunk and output it into text file for easy troubleshooting purposes. So far I have written a code that does that but it is extremely slow (takes hours to decode the whole file).

Here is my code:

```
template<class T> std::vector<T> readBytes(std::ifstream& input, int numOfBytes) {
    std::vector<T> output;
    output.reserve(numOfBytes);

    T* buf = new T[numOfBytes];
    input.read((char*)buf, sizeof(T) * numOfBytes);

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; ++i) {
        output.push_back(buf[i]);
    }
    
    delete[] buf;
    return output;
}

std::ifstream file("lidar_Mission.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
std::streampos total_bytes(file.tellg());
file.seekg(12, std::ios::beg); //skip the header

while (file) {
    if (file.good()) {
        //Read the required chunk and store it in a vector
        std::vector<std::int8_t> time(readBytes<std::int8_t>(file, 8));
        std::vector<std::int8_t> lidarx(readBytes<std::int8_t>(file, 4));
        std::vector<std::int8_t> lidary(readBytes<std::int8_t>(file, 4));
        std::vector<std::int8_t> lidarz(readBytes<std::int8_t>(file, 4));
        std::vector<std::int8_t> intensity(readBytes<std::int8_t>(file, 2));
        std::vector<char> classification(readBytes<char>(file, 1));
        std::vector<char> Return_scan(readBytes<char>(file, 1));

        uint8_t timeArr[8] = { time[0], time[1],time[2],time[3],time[4],time[5],time[6],time[7] };
        uint8_t lidarxArr[4] = { lidarx[0], lidarx[1],lidarx[2],lidarx[3] };
        uint8_t lidaryArr[4] = { lidary[0], lidary[1],lidary[2],lidary[3] };
        uint8_t lidarzArr[4] = { lidarz[0], lidarz[1],lidarz[2],lidarz[3] };
        uint8_t intenArr[2] = { intensity[0], intensity[1] };
        uint8_t clssArr[1] = { classification[0]};
        uint8_t Retn_scnArr[1] = { Return_scan[0]};
                
        //Type punning
        double timestamp = *((double*)&timeArr);
        float x = *((float*)lidarxArr);
        float y = *((float*)lidaryArr);
        float z = *((float*)lidarzArr);
        uint16_t inten = *((uint16_t*)intenArr);
        uint8_t clss = *((uint8_t*)clssArr);
        uint8_t Retn_scn = *((uint8_t*)Retn_scnArr);
        
        //Write to a text file
        std::ofstream fout;

        fout.open("test2", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);

        fout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9) << std::left << std::setw(19) << timestamp
            << std::setprecision(10) << std::setw(15) << x
            << std::setprecision(10) << std::setw(15) << y
            << std::setw(16) << z
            << std::setw(10) << inten
            << std::endl;
        fout.close();
    }else{
        throw std::exception();
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to make this run faster? Thanks

Comment: `read()` is a high overhead operation.  Try reading the file in larger chunks and working within those chunks.

Comment: Why do you read into an array that you `new`'d, loop over it and put it into a vector, and then `delete` the array? Just `resize` the vector and read directly into it.

Comment: building all those vectors is a waste.  It looks like you should just have `struct` of `double, float, float, float, uint16_t, uint8_t, uint8_t` and read it directly in one go.  If the input file is just an array of multiples of that structure, you can read a large number of them in a big chunk at a time.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen for your suggestions.

Comment: @Kevin, sorry what do you mean exactly? I have to read into a buffer first right? How do you read into the vector directly?

Comment: @MarkRansom and Mark Tolonen, I completely agree with you. I should probably read in large chunks and work with that. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Guled Like this: `std::vector<T> output(numOfBytes); input.read((char*)output.data(), sizeof(T) * numOfBytes); return output;` The vector internally holds an array of `T`, so there's no reason to make your own just to copy it into the vector. Just read directly into the vector's data.

Comment: @Kevin I have tried that before, the issue is the created vector holds zero elements. output.data() doesn't work for me. I will try to read the whole file once into a vector as follows: `std::vector<std::int8_t> output(fileSize); file.read((char*)&output[0], fileSize); file.close(); return output;` Then I will loop over using a for loop or something to do those operations.

Comment: @Guled `std::vector<T> output(numOfBytes);` creates a vector with `numOfBytes` elements of type T.

Comment: @Kevin thanks. Is there a better way to write to a text file, since the code I have for writing is slowing the program down: **fout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9) << std::left << std::setw(19) << lqc[k].timestamp**

Answer (score 0):

Do as much outside the loop as possible, especially i/o.  Open fout once before entering your loop, close it once after exiting it.  Also close the file if there is any fatal error, with an indication why the operation failed.

You might also test moving your other declarations outside the loop as well, referring to predefined variables within it.  If you aren't sure whether something like that might be optimized out by the compiler, it's an easy test to run.

Comment: Thanks @psimpson. Will definitely try that.